# What is the most reliable way to check for firefox installation?

Tags: firefox, installation, inno-setup

I am making a software that comes bundled with a firefox extension. In my instalation script I want to prompt a user weather he wants to install the extension. But for that I need:

1. A way to tell if firefox is installed or not
2. A way to tell which version of firefox is installed

How would I do these two things in InnoSetup or C#? I tried manually checking the path to default firefox install dir or checking for uninstall records in registry. I think that these methods are not reliable at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recommended way is checking whether `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox` registry key exists. There will be a subkey for each installed version. If you are paranoid, you can also check the value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\<version>\Main\PathToExe` - if that file exists then Firefox is really installed and you aren't looking at a stale registry key.

Note that you can only detect a Firefox installation only if the installer was actually used. You can always "install" Firefox manually, simply by unpacking the setup executable with 7zip - into any directory. Nightly builds are also available as regular zip files that are easier to unpack. This will work just fine but won't add any registry keys that will allow you to find this installation.

Comment: I should add that this path is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox for 64bit windows.

Comment: Yes, if you access the registry from an x64 app (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896459). Note that an x64 version of Firefox should be available soon, then you will have to check both locations.

Comment: I've seen a user's machine who doesn't have anything in HKLM but does have entries under HKCU. Is it now possible to install Firefox only under the user directory, like Chrome does?

Comment: @Rory: You can only detect a Firefox installation if the installer was used (I will add a note on this to the answer). Anybody can simply use 7zip to unpack the executable into any directory they want - this will work just fine, administrator privileges not necessary. Also, there is Firefox Portable which doesn't need to be installed. But if you are using the installer, from all I know only global installations are supported.

Comment: A note from 2016 (when FF x64 has been released for a while): the `Wow6432Node` check seems unnecessary. The install path is still on the regular reg key.

Comment: @thomasb: It's always the regular registry key. However, you can still install a 32-bit version of Firefox and check the registry key via some 64-bit application. If you do that, you have to consider registry redirection - meaning looking under `Wow6432Node`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a shortened list of created keys (by Firefox 27.0.1 installation)

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\FirefoxHTML\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\FirefoxURL\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\FIREFOX.EXE\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe\Path
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Mozilla Firefox 27.0.1 (x86 en-US)\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\27.0.1 (en-US)\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox 27.0.1\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet\FIREFOX.EXE\
```

One of our client did not have the "Uninstall" one so we'll use another from that list.
I am going to use: "firefox is installed when at least one of the following keys exists:"

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\FIREFOX.EXE\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet\FIREFOX.EXE\
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\FIREFOX.EXE` key isn't dependent from OS bits, so I suggest this.